# How would i implement a Generic ArrayList of Fragments in Android?

Tags: java, android, generics, arraylist, android-fragments

So I am trying to implement a method that uses all of my `Fragment` classes to create an `Array List<? extends Fragment>` in my `MainActivity.java` class which is an `ArrayList` with different objects that extend the `Fragment` class.

The primary reason why I am doing this is to load fragments using the `android.support.v4.jar` support library `ViewPager` view.

Here is what i Have so far, but I cannot add the different Objects that `extend Fragment` into my `ArrayList`

```
public List<? extends Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<? extends Fragment> ipsumFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    ipsumFragments.add(BaconIpsumFragment.newInstance());
    ipsumFragments.add(BuseyIpsumFragment.newInstance());
    ipsumFragments.add(LoremIpsumFragment.newInstance());

    return ipsumFragments;
}
```

I am just trying to get my head around using a ViewPager and multiple fragments.If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

And here is my class for The first `Fragment`, the others are exactly the same but named different and use different `XML` layouts

```
public class BaconIpsumFragment extends Fragment{

public static final BaconIpsumFragment newInstance(){

    BaconIpsumFragment baconFragment = new BaconIpsumFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    baconFragment.setArguments(args);
    return baconFragment;   
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    // Attempt to attach to the parent activity
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

// Called when the parent activity creates the fragment
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Perform the default behavior
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bacon_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Last attempt to change any variables
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

}
```

And the full implementation of my activity. My error is occurring in the getFragments() method when trying to add an instance of a fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ActionBar tabbedActionBar = null;   
private String [] ipsumsArray = null;
private Resources resources = null;
private FragmentManager manager = null;
private FragmentTransaction transaction = null;

private List<Fragment> mIpsumFragments = null;
private LoremIpsumViewPager pagerAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the resources object
    resources = getResources();
    // get the String array from resources
    ipsumsArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ipsums_array);

    // Get all the fragments that we will attempt to display
    mIpsumFragments = getFragments();

    // get a reference to the action bar
    tabbedActionBar = getActionBar();
    // set the navigation mode for the action bar
    tabbedActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (int i = 0; i < ipsumsArray.length; i++){
        Tab tab = tabbedActionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText(ipsumsArray[i]);
        tab.setTabListener(tabListener);
        tabbedActionBar.addTab(tab);
    }

//      setDefaultTab();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private TabListener tabListener = new TabListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

        // Get the fragment manager
        manager = getFragmentManager();
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();


        int tabSelected = tab.getPosition();


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};



private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
    List<Fragment> ipsumFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    ipsumFragments.add(BaconIpsumFragment.newInstance());
    ipsumFragments.add(BuseyIpsumFragment.newInstance());
    ipsumFragments.add(LoremIpsumFragment.newInstance());

    return ipsumFragments;
}

}
```

Comment: I can't believe that you are getting that error while adding instances to the `List`. This is simply not possible. Just like you can have a super class reference holding a subclass object, you can add a subclass instance to a super class list.

Comment: Please re-check again. I can't figure out if there is some android related issue, as I'm not an Android guy.

Comment: I saw this tutorial http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using and they do not seem to have an issue with this. . .

Comment: So, I see there this isn't a generics related issue anymore. It's something else. Try to figure out why going through your code. May be ask another question, as I won't be able to help in android issue. Sorry for that. :(

Comment: If asking the same question again, you can avoid giving whole code again, by linking this question there. And only give relevant code, with exact error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use wildcard at all. Just declare your list as:

```
List<Fragment> ipsumFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

It doesn't restrict you to add just the instances of `Fragment` in the list. You will be able to add instances of subclasses of `Fragment` in it too. And then change the return type of your method to `List<Fragment>`.

The use of declaring a list as `List<? extends Fragment>` is that you can assign that reference, list of any subclass of `Fragment`. So, you can assign `List<BaconIpsumFragment>`, `List<LoremIpsumFragment>`, that's it. And that is the reason why you can't add instances of any subclass in such lists, because you don't know what list do you have actually underneath. So, you might be trying to add a `BaconIpsumFragment` into a `List<LoremIpsumFragment>`, which is certainly not correct.

Comment: When i make this change, Eclipse is telling me that add is not Applicable for the type BaconIpsumFragment which is a class that extends Fragment. My newInstance() method in this class returns a BaconIpsumFragment. Should i be casting this to a fragment?

Comment: @inner_class7. There is no need to cast if you are adding a subclass instance of `Fragment`. Can you show your code, and class structure.

Comment: here i added one of the other classes. The rest are the same just using different xml and different class names.

Comment: That error message you show is not for when you add something to the list. It's for something else. Please show the code that shows that error.

Comment: I am adding my MainActivity class above.