# NullPointerException when trying to access a Fragment in a ArrayList after screen reload. How can I achieve this?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I was trying to programmatically add to my activity a list of fragments which implement some CardViews. These CardViews have some TextViews that I want to set from my Activity, and it works setting them on `onStart` or `onResume` events. Or no... is better to say, *almost* works. When there's a screen rotation (and anything that would force the restart of an Activity), trying to do anything to any fragment on `onStart` and `onRestart` results on a NullPointerException. Basically I have:

**MyActivity.java**

```
private List<MyFragment> cards = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rucardapio); 

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        /* Here I create 10 fragment cards */
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cards.add(new MyFragment());
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, cards.get(i));
        }

        transaction.commit();

   }

}
```

After some tests I figured out that the problem possibly is on `if (savedInstanceState != null) { return; }`. I tried these "solutions", however,  which didn't helped me: [NullPointerException when accessing a Fragment's textView in an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389938/nullpointerexception-when-accessing-a-fragments-textview-in-an-activity) , 
[NPE thrown when trying to Find Button ID in Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748277/npe-thrown-when-trying-to-find-button-id-in-android-fragment) , 
[How would i implement a Generic ArrayList of Fragments in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534804/how-would-i-implement-a-generic-arraylist-of-fragments-in-android) and much more...

---

Logcat:

```
01-24 09:07:21.848  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 43
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.878  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 47
01-24 09:07:21.888  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 48
01-24 09:07:40.088  30751-30751/io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu, PID: 30751
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at io.github.mths0x5f.guiaufu.ru.MyActivity$2.run(MyActivity.java:161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Piece of code that work on cold start but not on "reload":

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ((TextView) cards.get(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Test");
}
```

Comment: post you logcat please....... and  you said " CardViews have some TextViews that I want to set from my Activity"  post this code block..... may be try to set null value during fragment reinitialization.....

Comment: Done. Added Logcat and the single-line method as you asked.